# Apache MQ: SEVERE: A child container failed during start, Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Destination

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am just calling a sample code to put a `Message` on to the `Queue` (Apache MQ) hosted on my local machine.

My Code:

```
public class Search extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String regID = null;
    //protected JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

   /**
    * Default constructor. 
    */
    public Search() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

   /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse  response)
    */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

   /**
    * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher rd = null;
        String function = request.getParameter("function");

        if (function.equals("VerificationSuccess")) {
            String userEmail=request.getParameter("email");

            // Create a hash map
            HashMap hm = new HashMap();

            // Put elements to the map
            hm.put("regID", regID);
            LdapUpdate lupdate = new LdapUpdate();          
            HashMap hmGet = lupdate.updateUser(hm);
            String uid = (String) hmGet.get("uid");
            String  creator = (String) hmGet.get("creator");
            try {
                ActiveMQConnectionFactory factory = new  ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");

                // Note that a new thread is created by createConnection, and it
                //  does not stop even if connection.stop() is called. We must
                //  shut down the JVM using System.exit() to end the program
                Connection connection = factory.createConnection();

                // Start the connection
                connection.start();

                // Create a non-transactional session with automatic acknowledgement
                Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

                // Create a reference to the queue test_queue in this session. Note
                //  that ActiveMQ has auto-creation enabled by default, so this JMS
                //  destination will be created on the broker automatically
                Queue queue = session.createQueue("test_queue");

                // Create a producer for test_queue
                MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

                // Create a simple text message and send it
                TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage ("Hello, world!");
                producer.send(message);

                // Stop the connection — good practice but redundant here
                connection.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
            request.setAttribute("uid", uid);
            rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("ApplicationAccess.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this code as a normal Java code in a `Main` class, it works fine and puts the `Message` onto the `Queue`. However, when I use it within a function, I am getting the following error:

```
INFO: Initialization processed in 923 ms
Feb 14, 2015 2:03:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 14, 2015 2:03:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.15
Feb 14, 2015 2:03:12 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [659] milliseconds.
Feb 14, 2015 2:03:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/UserRegistrationTwo]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component  [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/UserRegistrationTwo]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/jms/Destination
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2499)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1811)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:132)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:334)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:774)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5095)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.jms.Destination
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
... 20 more

Feb 14, 2015 2:03:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]] at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:868)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

Feb 14, 2015 2:03:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:625)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
 at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:760)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:439)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:925)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more

Feb 14, 2015 2:03:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8181"]
Feb 14, 2015 2:03:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 14, 2015 2:03:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Feb 14, 2015 2:03:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8181"]
Feb 14, 2015 2:03:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8181"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)

Feb 14, 2015 2:03:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Feb 14, 2015 2:03:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:307)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:482)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:795)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:531)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:588)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:850)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:629)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:351)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:485)
```

Comment: does your `WEB-INF/lib` contain ActiveMQ jar?

Comment: Thanks Vihar..Its resolved. I had to put the jar file in the Lib folder.

Comment: Just a tip, it's a really bad idea to create a ConnectionFactory + Connection every time you want to send a message - your performance will be horrible. You want one Connection instance shared across multiple HTTP requests, and create a Session and MessageProducer each time. Also make sure to close your Session when you are done with it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to deploy the ActiveMQ jar in the following path, and after that the issue got resolved.

```
WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/activemq-all-5.10.0.jar
```